# Proguard result in "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ActivityMain}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class]" for ViewModels factory

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-jetpack

Attempt to use Proguard result in "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ActivityMain}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class app.example.data.BaseRepository]". Crash log:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class app.example.data.BaseRepository]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2327)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
        at app.aegis.browser.ui.common.ViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelFactory.kt:31)
        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)
        at app.example.ui.ActivityMain.getSharedVM(Unknown Source:2)
        at app.example.ui.ActivityMain.onCreate(ActivityMain.kt:39)
```

Activity code:

```
class ActivityMain : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val sharedVM by viewModels<ConfigViewModel> {
        ViewModelFactory(App.getRep(),this)
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        sharedVM.exit.observe(this, Observer {  }) // line 39

    }

}
```

Factory code:

```
modelClass
    .getConstructor(BaseRepository::class.java) // offending string 31
    .newInstance(baseRepository)
```

ViewModel:

```
class ConfigViewModel(repository: BaseRepository) : ViewModel(), VMRepository { }
```

I've tried using "ConfigViewModel @JvmOverloads public constructor(repository: BaseRepository)", using empty constructor as default and then adding alternative one with BaseRepository - it didn't work.

Any cure for this? Like, for example a rule for Proguard to not "optimize" ViewModel files at all.

edit: the only acceptable workaround I've found so far is ProGuard rule which basically defeat ProGuard's purpose (obfuscation) for half of the code in the application:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(app.example.data.BaseRepository);
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get any further with this Pavel?  I'm seeing the same thing, also with a ViewModelFactory.  I used a similar workaround to yours, but added the `@Keep` annotation for my ViewModel class.  Which, as you say, somewhat defeats the purpose of obfuscation.

Comment: No progress so far.